# Difference between res.send and res.json in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

What is actual difference between `res.send` and `res.json` as both seems to perform same operation of responding to client.

Comment: Take a moment to note how the folks posting answers just went to github and read the source code. This is a good habit to learn and establish. The Truth lies in The Source.

Comment: @PeterLyons I agree this is a good habit, but did you mean that ram should have looked at the source instead of asking the question? Doesn't this defeat the purpose of this site? The presence of this question, with answers referring to a good source (The Source!) is useful.

Comment: Yes, teach a man to fish and all.

Comment: When we are told "RTFS" (Read The Source) it actually means that the docs fail to communicate what they should.
Yes, having the source allows us to check it, but one should need not to get to it except in obscure cases. 
All these Express features are Really Great, but the docs fall short, by a lot. SO is full of questions about Express things that people can't understand from the docs (happens to me).

Comment: Sometimes reading source is not sufficient and as a good explanation may arise from answers, this will ensure the best understanding of the concept involved. Some people would simply read source and understand, but what about beginners who are not necessarily javascript friendly ? Think about it.

Comment: @PeterLyons but asking the question on here instead wins internet points ;) Question has 79 upvotes at time of writing.

Comment: I agree that docs are poor if they don't explain basics like these, and we should all stop badgering new engineers to "read the source" until they're ready to

Comment: As a junior dev, I found @PeterLyons comment to be very useful. It's useful to note that there's another option when I'm confused- read the source code. I've seen people do this once or twice, but hadn't yet made it part of my debugging steps. Now I will. His comment doesn't negate the awesomeness of SO, but, rather, helps new coders realize there's another tool to put in our toolbelt :-)

Answer (score 264, accepted):

The methods are identical when an object or array is passed, but `res.json()` will also convert non-objects, such as `null` and `undefined`, which are not valid JSON.

The method also uses the `json replacer` and `json spaces` application settings, so you can format JSON with more options. Those options are set like so:

```
app.set('json spaces', 2);
app.set('json replacer', replacer);
```

And passed to a `JSON.stringify()` like so:

```
JSON.stringify(value, replacer, spacing);
// value: object to format
// replacer: rules for transforming properties encountered during stringifying
// spacing: the number of spaces for indentation
```

This is the code in the `res.json()` method that the `res.send()` method doesn't have:

```
var app = this.app;
var replacer = app.get('json replacer');
var spaces = app.get('json spaces');
var body = JSON.stringify(obj, replacer, spaces);
```

The method ends up as a `res.send()` in the end:

```
this.charset = this.charset || 'utf-8';
this.get('Content-Type') || this.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

return this.send(body);
```

Answer (score 92):

See: [`res.json` source code on expressjs](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/ee228f7aea6448cf85cc052697f8d831dce785d5/lib/response.js#L174).

`res.json` eventually calls `res.send`, but before that it:

- respects the `json spaces` and `json replacer` app settings
- ensures the response will have `utf-8` charset and `application/json` Content-Type

Answer (score 24):

Looking in the headers sent...

`res.send` uses `content-type:text/html`

`res.json` uses `content-type:application/json`

edit: send actually changes what is sent based on what it's given, so strings are sent as `text/html`, but if you pass it an object it emits `application/json`.

Answer (score 2):

`res.json` forces the argument to JSON.  `res.send` will take an non-json object or non-json array and send another type.  For example:

This will return a JSON number.

```
res.json(100)
```

This will return a status code and issue a warning to use `sendStatus`.

```
res.send(100)
```

If your argument is not a JSON object or array (`null`, `undefined`, `boolean`, `string`), and you want to ensure it is sent as JSON, use `res.json`.

Comment: In this sentence: `will take an non-json object or array` -> we read it like: `non-json object` or `array`. so please make it more clear if possible.