# difference between res.send or res.json

Tags: node.js, express

What is the difference between

```
res.status(STATUS_CODE).send({"message" : "this is the message" });
```

and

```
res.status(STATUS_CODE).json({"message" : "this is the message" });
```

although checked [the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041837/difference-between-res-send-and-res-json-in-express-js) but that is in context of express 3  and I am looking for express 4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between res.send and res.json in Express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041837/difference-between-res-send-and-res-json-in-express-js)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ultimately, both will achieve the same thing. If you call `res.send` with an object, it will hit this switch in `res.send`:

```
switch (typeof chunk) {
// string defaulting to html
case 'string':
  if (!this.get('Content-Type')) {
    this.type('html');
  }
  break;
case 'boolean':
case 'number':
case 'object':
  if (chunk === null) {
    chunk = '';
  } else if (Buffer.isBuffer(chunk)) {
    if (!this.get('Content-Type')) {
      this.type('bin');
    }
  } else {
    return this.json(chunk);
  }
  break;
}
```

If the object you're sending it is not a Buffer - it will call `res.json`.

`res.json` simply sets the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` and runs the object through `JSON.stringify` - with specified replacer function and spacer value. Eventually it calls `res.send`.

This call of `res.send` is sent a string and the case statement will break resulting in the rest of the function being run. The remainder of the send function sets things like etag, content size etc. You can find out more by looking at the [express code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L99-L208).

They start to differ when you send them non-object responses, such as strings, numbers etc. As in that case `res.json` will run it through `JSON.stringify` but `res.send` wont: resulting in different `Content-Type` headers and content.

edit: to answer your comment on the other answer, sending different status codes will still behave the same.

Comment: I havn't specified replacer function and spacer value  on any page and  running `res.json`, does this break some way?

Comment: No, in that case it just uses the default (which is undefined). Effectively resulting in a vanilla call to JSON.stringify().

Comment: do not understand :( do I need to write `.send(JSON.stringify({"message" :"message here"}))`?

Comment: Ah, no. Sorry. You don't need to do that. You can ignore the replacer and spacer settings. They are for controlling how the json is formatted, default is fine for most cases.

Answer (score 4):

`.json` calls `.toJSON()` method on the object (if it exists) and also sets the `content-type` header to `application/json`

But basically you can simulate `.json` with `.send`, if you do the above manually.

---

For example this middleware

```
(req, res, next) => {
    let x = {};
    x.toJSON = () => {
        console.log('oh yeah');
        return 15;
    };

    return res.json(x);
}
```

Prints

```
oh yeah
```

And returns `15` to the request with these headers (at least in my simple express app):

```
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Length →2
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Date →Wed, 08 Jun 2016 10:16:09 GMT
ETag →W/"2-m/Mcf/Bik2qW08i9H48v8w"
Vary →Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By →Express
```

Comment: does this work even when we have status code 404 or 500?

Comment: error messages can be in json too, therefore it does not limit you to use any status codes you wish.