# Node.js how to read json data from request?

Tags: json, node.js, express

I have a server as following:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
   console.log(req);
   res.json({ message: 'pppppppppppppssssssssssssss ' });   
});
```

The request is sent from a client as:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: self.serverURI,
    data: JSON.stringify({ "a": "128", "b": "7" }),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

so far the connection fine.

My problem is in the server:

```
console.log(req);
```

where I want to read the data I sent. How can I read `{ "a": "128", "b": "7" }` from `req`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although you're not mentioning it, your code looks like it's written for an [Express](http://expressjs.com) environment. My answer is targeted to this.

Make sure to use [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) for Express. In case, your project depends on some generated boilerplate code, it's most likely already included in your main server script. If not:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Installation with npm: `npm install body-parser --save`

The parsed JSON can then be accessed through `req.body`:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body); // not a string, but your parsed JSON data
    console.log(req.body.a); // etc.
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. Finally ufffffff.  It would be great if you could explain how can I send such a JSon to client by "res" parameter :)

Comment: `res.json(object)` is the correct way to go. As already given in your sample code.

Comment: I read many tutorials. Some use "res.json(object)", some use "res.end(something)", quite confusing for people who new to this.

Comment: `res.json` will automatically set the response `content-type` header to `application/json`, while `res.send` will set `text/html` by default. If you're returning JSON, definitely use the `res.json` function.

Comment: More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041837/difference-between-res-send-and-res-json-in-express-js

Comment: I am trying to send a large data as JSon, is there any example of constructing JSon data and send back? I think I need to define a function for construct  JSon and send by "res.json(data)". Could  you show me an example of it? I would appreciate it

Comment: To keep things here on topic, rather open a new post for this. I can have a look later on :)

Comment: I try myself first, then ask if have troubles :) thx, you helped a lot

Comment: Well is that really something that can't be solved without external library?

Answer (score 5):

For Express 4+,

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
```

Then, you can use `req.body` as expected.

```
app.post("/api", (req, res) => {
  /*
    If the post request included { data: "foo" },
    then you would access `data` like so:
  */
  req.body.data
  ...
});
```