# use for loop in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i am using for loop to retrieve the data from mongodb and display it on the browser but the problem it it iterates only for the first time and stops. So i get only the first entry as the output. Whereas it gives the correct output in the console log. Please help?

```
var movieSchema1 = new mongoose.Schema({
  name:String,
  address:String,
  location:String
});

var user=mongoose.model('movie', movieSchema1, 'movie');

for (var i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
  res.json("iteration " + i);
  res.json('name:' + user[i].name + user[i].address);
}
```

Comment: Where is user defined/initialized? Not shown in your code snippet above.

Comment: res.json only wants to be called once.  Build up your result first, maybe use an array for this.

Comment: @Keith please help me with it?how to do it?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll ya it is initialized

Comment: `res.json()` sends an object and then ENDs the response.  You cannot ever call it more than once on the same response object and expect it to work.  Build your object in the loop and then `res.json()` it at the end.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, build up an object for your response, then res.json() it. Because you're trying to send an array, just use .map() to transform each one:

```
//turn the array of users into the objects we want to send
const responseData = user.map( (movie, i) => {
   return {
      iteration: i,
      name: movie.name + ' ' + movie.address
   };
});

//this converts the array to a string for you
res.json( responseData );
```

Comment: Yes this works,but it gives the output in json format,i simply want to display the key and value without json format ?what changes need to be done

Comment: nice answer! @DuncanThacker

Comment: You need to get each index and the value then write it to the response @RadhikaObhan check my update

Comment: If you don't want JSON, why are you using res.json()?

Comment: @DuncanThacker what alternate can I use to display only key and value data?

Comment: Not clear to me what format you're expecting in the output. "Key and value data" doesn't really narrow it down, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find()` method to receive all of the objects from a schema.

```
var response;  

user.find({}, function(err, users){
       if(err) throw err;
       if(users.length != 0){
          response = users.map((user, i) => {
             return {
               index: i,
               name: user.name + ' ' + user.address
             };             
       }
    })
    for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
       res.write('Key: ' i + ' the value: ' response[i] + '\n');
    }
    res.end();
```

You should also use `res.json()` once only, as it will return `Can't set headers after they are sent` **error**.

Please see  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041837/difference-between-res-send-and-res-json-in-express-js) for info on `res.json()`

Comment: can we see your code? where does the `res` go to? @RadhikaObhan

Comment: @turmuka, you do the same as OP, trying to send response for each user. Use `map` to create an array of objects and after that send it.

Comment: true, I just saw the mistake there, gonna edit it in a sec @alexmac