# Can't use console.log inside app.get method, but works outside of it

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I am having a problem I can't fix. Every time I type console inside my app.get method I can't log anything. I can't call any other methods related to console either.
I've tried reinstalling nodejs, deleting node modules, it doesn't matter if I use a different IDE (VS Code, WebStorm, Brackets) I always get this odd error where it just shows this:
[picture of broken console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJREe.png)

I don't know how to fix this and I'm confused about what I did to even break the console to no longer have access to any of its methods.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, no pictures of code. Always copy/paste and put it a code block.

As for your issue, you're trying to add a console log to the payload you're sending in the response. Where would this console log be output, when it has already been sent in the response, outside of your app?

If you want to log inside app.get, do this:

```
app.get('url', (req, res) => {
  console.log('hello world')
  res.status(200).send("hello");
});
```

You can also add the json instead, but you should use EITHER res.send() or res.json().

See here for the difference:

[Difference between res.send and res.json in Express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041837/difference-between-res-send-and-res-json-in-express-js)

Comment: Thank you, I think I've been coding for too long today, I thought that I could console.log the req.params inside the res.json, I appreciate the help, if I might ask, how come no pictures of code?

Comment: Happens to everyone :) For the pictures of code thing, check out this discussion: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1):

By going through the image, the reason why console.log() is not working is that you're using it inside a json object.

When you do `res.status(200).json()` you pass the response json as a parameter.

The json can only contain valid javascript keys and values. It cannot contain function executions (as functions cannot be serialised)

wooooooo's answer is correct. Use console.log() or any other function outside `res.json()`.

[Know more about `res.json()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json)