# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

My backend in `node.js` and `express.js`

```js
    import express from 'express';
    import bcrypt from 'bcrypt-nodejs';
    import cors from 'cors';
    
    const app = express();
    
    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(cors());
    const database = { users: [
        {
            id: '123',
            name: 'John',
            email: 'john@gmail.com',
            password: 'cookies',
            entries: 0,
            joined: new Date()
        },
        {
            id: '124',
            name: 'Tom',
            email: 'Tom@gmail.com',
            password: 'apple',
            entries: 0,
            joined: new Date()
        }
    
    }
    
    app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
        res.send(database.users)
    })
    
    
    app.listen(3002, () => {
       console.log('app is running on port 3002');
    })
```

My frontend is in `React.js`

It is a big project so I will only show the part that is causing the error which is the `response.json()` part. When you get rid of `json()` everything is fine but for me to receive data from the backend i need to do `.json()` which gives that error. Let me know if additional info is needed

```js
      componentDidMount(){
        fetch('http://localhost:3000')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(console.log)
      }
```

Comment: You are fetching wrong port. Your server listening on 3002 port so on fetch change it url to "http://localhost:3002". And on your get request use "res.json()" instead "res.send", this will return the response with correct header. For details you can [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041837/difference-between-res-send-and-res-json-in-express-js).

Answer (score 6):

Looks like your backend is exposed on port 3002 but you're fetching on port 3000 which I assume is your local development UI. The `DOCTYPE` response is indicative of you receiving HTML rather than a JSON response. Change the port of your fetch to point towards your backend and it should work:

```
 componentDidMount(){
    fetch('http://localhost:3002')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(console.log)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

For those using Next.js, make sure that the `api` related files are in `api` folder.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was an issue with the React package.json file.

> I added the   `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080",` to the `package.json` file. so the problem was fixed.

React is running on port `3000`,
and express is running on port `8080`

Comment: like this ?
`{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
  "private": true,
}
`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was while working with the new Visual Studio template (React ts + .NET Core).
I resolved it by adding a specific proxy rule for dev server in the vite.config.ts file.

Added the following lines referring to the new controller which api was returning the specified error.
**'^/mycontrollername': {
target: 'https://localhost:7093/',
secure: false**

```
 server: {
 proxy: {
     '^/weatherforecast': {
         target: 'https://localhost:7093/',
         secure: false
     },
     **'^/mycontrollername': {
         target: 'https://localhost:7093/',
         secure: false
     }**
 },
 port: 5173,
 https: {
     key: fs.readFileSync(keyFilePath),
     cert: fs.readFileSync(certFilePath),
 }
```

}

For more information about configuring Vite config file:
https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-proxy

Answer (score 0):

This problem can occur if one adds a proxy to the package.json file to overcome CORS but then failing to run npm install to update dependencies.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error with Vite and this is how I solved it. If you're using vite check if you have to use a proxy. you can add the below code inside vite.config.js inside defineConfig.

```
server: {
    port: 3000,
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, "/api"),
      },
    },
  },
```