# Debugging React display

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, crud

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-react-crud) and I've run across a problem. The client list will not display on the webpage like the following image (it just states client):
[image]

This is the code that displays it:

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        clients: []
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        const response = await fetch('/clients');
        const body = await response.json();
        this.setState({clients: body});
    }

    render() {
        const {clients} = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                    <div className="App-intro">
                        <h2>Clients</h2>
                        {clients.map(client =>
                            <div key={client.id}>
                                {client.name} ({client.email})
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </header>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

I was wondering how I could try to debug the react code to display the client list.

At first, I had trouble generating clients, so I assumed that was the problem. I am able to generate clients, the problem is simply displaying them.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by looking at the developer tools and following this stackoverflow entry: [x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73590839/uncaught-in-promise-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-doctype-is-not)